# Can I implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener in a class which extends FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, searchview

I am trying to hide the soft keyboard and collapse/dismiss the search item in a class which extends FragmentActivity.
I know the best place to do this is in the onQueryTextSubmit.
I have implemented  SearchView.OnQueryTextListene.
I have defined the class as the listener, searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
BUT the  onQueryTextSubmit(String query) is never called.

I had a doubt about using this in a FragmentActivity, so I created a test project using a class which extends Activity. I coded it exactly the same way as the above example and it worked fine.

So I think there may be a bug and the onQueryTextSubmit(String query) is not called from a class which extends a FragmentActivity.

Has anyone managed to solve this problem.

Thanks